How to display text saved as JSON by a Lexical editor, in another Lexical editor in readOnly mode?
I'm using Lexical to add a rich text editor to a React project. To test how this works, I've added two Lexical editors to a single page. One editor is "editable", the other is in read only mode. I have a save button that should allow the text from one editor to be displayed in the other.
I would like to be able to display text in a Lexical editor that has previously been saved as a JSON string.
Here is my full code:
import {AutoFocusPlugin} from '@lexical/react/LexicalAutoFocusPlugin';
import {LexicalComposer} from '@lexical/react/LexicalComposer';
import {ContentEditable} from '@lexical/react/LexicalContentEditable';
import {LexicalErrorBoundary} from '@lexical/react/LexicalErrorBoundary';
import {HistoryPlugin} from '@lexical/react/LexicalHistoryPlugin';
import {RichTextPlugin} from '@lexical/react/LexicalRichTextPlugin';
import {OnChangePlugin} from '@lexical/react/LexicalOnChangePlugin';
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from "@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext";


import ExampleTheme from './ExampleTheme.ts';
import ToolbarPlugin from './ToolbarPlugin.tsx';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
// import TreeViewPlugin from './TreeViewPlugin.tsx';

function Placeholder() {
  return <div className="editor-placeholder">Enter some rich text...</div>;
}

const editorConfig = {
  namespace: 'Editor',
  nodes: [],
  // Handling of errors during update
  onError(error: Error) {
    throw error;
  },
  // The editor theme
  theme: ExampleTheme,
};

const readerConfig = {
  namespace: 'Reader',
  nodes: [],
  // Handling of errors during update
  onError(error: Error) {
    throw error;
  },
  // The editor theme
  theme: ExampleTheme,
  editable: false,
};


export default function TextEditor() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState<string>();
  const [readerState, setReaderState] = useState<string>();
  
  function UpdatePlugin() {
    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
    editor.setEditorState(editor.parseEditorState(readerState));

    return null;
  }

  function onChange(editorState) {
    const editorStateJSON = editorState.toJSON();
    setEditorState(JSON.stringify(editorStateJSON));
  }
  
  function toggleEditable(){
    console.log("toggling editability")
  }

  function saveButton() {
      console.log(editorState);
      setReaderState(editorState);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
        <div className="editor-container">
          <ToolbarPlugin />
          <div className="editor-inner">
            <RichTextPlugin
              contentEditable={<ContentEditable className="editor-input" />}
              placeholder={<Placeholder />}
              ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
            />
            <HistoryPlugin />
            <AutoFocusPlugin />
            <OnChangePlugin onChange={onChange} />
            {/* <TreeViewPlugin /> */}
          </div>
          <button
            className='text-edit-button'
            title='Update overview description'
            onClick={() => saveButton()}
            >Print to reader</button>
            <button
            className='text-edit-button'
            title='Update overview description'
            onClick={() => toggleEditable()}
            >Toggle</button>
        </div>
      </LexicalComposer>

      <LexicalComposer initialConfig={readerConfig}>
        <div className="editor-container">
          <div className="editor-inner">
            <RichTextPlugin
              contentEditable={<ContentEditable className="editor-input" />}
              placeholder={<Placeholder />}
              ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
            />
            <UpdatePlugin />
          </div>
            <button
            className='text-edit-button'
            title='Update overview description'
            onClick={() => toggleEditable()}
            >Toggle</button>
        </div>
      </LexicalComposer>
    </div>
  );
}

This code produces the following error message:
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | SerializedEditorState<SerializedLexicalNode>'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | SerializedEditorState<SerializedLexicalNode>'.
However, when the following lines are commented out, the page loads correctly:
  function UpdatePlugin() {
    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
    editor.setEditorState(editor.parseEditorState(readerState));

    return null;
  }

And:
<UpdatePlugin />
Once the page is loaded, I can uncomment those lines, save the file, and the page works as intended. However, when I refresh the page, I receive Uncaught runtime errors:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')
at parseEditorState
